# Using Ubuntu For Android using Kivy

Tags: 14.04, android

I just want to ask can I use Ubuntu 14.04 for developing an Android application using Kivy? And if so, then which packages do I need to download from Kivy's website??

Comment: Yes. Use the Ubuntu PPA.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the download page [here](http://kivy.org/#download) you find a ppa, and a guide how to use the ppa if you need that.